# Grub window not display and directly open ubuntu in dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I have an SSD and HDD. In my SSD I am using windows 10. SSD has no Partition. 
Recently I installed ubuntu in my HDD. Installed successfully. after restart PC Grub window not display and directly open windows 10. 
I found a solution from Google and I apply that by "try ubuntu" and update grub by the terminal. Grub updated successfully. 
After restarting, PC directly start ubuntu and no Grub window display when starting PC.

Now, How can I boot windows 10 and display Grub window when start pc?

Comment: "SSD has no partition" -> no, it must be full partitionned by Windows, so a NTFS partition; and to answer at your question, using `grub` with 2 OS installed on 2 different disk can have issues sometimes; try `sudo update-grub` and reboot

Comment: sorry about partition. @damadam